# I sent usdt to my smart contract

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have send by mistake usdt(polygon) to my smart contract that’s token contract created on bsc network.
Is there any chance to pull that token out ?

When I execute transfer function it only pull funds from bsc.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you have sent tokens to an address which doesn't have anything because you accidentally used the wrong network.

Whoever deployed the contract in the correct network could, in theory, also deploy a contract to the same address in the network where you sent the tokens. So you could try to contact the contract deployer - or if that's you, you can just deploy a token retrieving contract in the right network.

Just make sure the deployed contract does what you need it to do: there is only one chance the deploy a contract to that address (except some very special trickery).

Comment: I’m the contract owner, so If I deploy the contract with my owner address I should get same smart contract address on different chain ?

Comment: Can you show me example of smart contract that’s used to pull out usdt on polygon ?

Comment: You have to use the same nonce and same deployer address. So you basically have to know what you're doing. Same goes for the contract code part